# Traverse all nodes and yield keys and value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, traversal

Given a JSON structure

```
var json = {
  'a': {
    'a1': ['a1a', 'a1b', 'a1c'],
    'a2': ['a2a', 'a2b'],
    'a3': []
  },
  'b': {
    'b1': ['b1a', 'b1b', 'b1c', 'b1d'],
    'b2': ['b2a', 'b2b'],
  },
  'c': ['c1', 'c2'],
  'd': {
    'd1': ['d1a', 'd1b', 'd1c'],
    'd2': []
  },
  'e': ['e1', 'e2'],
  'f': [
    'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9', 'f10'
  ]
};
```

Using Javascript how can I traverse this to **yield** an array of all keys and values?  In other words, without simply keeping an external store and append to it as I traverse, how can I return an array of the entire set of node keys and values?

For example in Python I might make use of a generator.  So perhaps I should ask, how can I use a generator in Javascript?

Javascript example with jQuery:

```
function traverse(jsonObj) {
  if( typeof jsonObj == "object" ) {
    $.each(jsonObj, function(k,v) {
      traverse(v);
    });
  }
  else {
    // how can I yield this value instead?
    console.log(jsonObj)
  }
}
```

Where my expected output would be an array of all keys and values:

```
['a', 'a1', 'a1a', 'a1b', 'a1c', 'a2', 'a2a', 'a2b'] // ... and so on
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECMAScript 6 has [**generators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*). So you can write the function as

```
function *traverse(value) {
  if (typeof value === "object") {
    var isArray = Array.isArray(value);
    for (var prop in value) {
        if (!isArray) yield prop;
        yield* traverse(value[prop]);
    }
  }
  else {
    yield value;
  }
}
```

And use it as:

```
var obj = {
  'a': {
    'a1': ['a1a', 'a1b', 'a1c'],
    'a2': ['a2a', 'a2b'],
    'a3': []
  }
};

console.log(Array.from(traverse(obj)));
```

[**DEMO via 6to5**](http://6to5.org/repl/#?experimental=true&playground=true&evaluate=true&code=%20%20%20%20function%20*traverse(value)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20value%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22object%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20isArray%20%3D%20Array.isArray(value)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(var%20prop%20in%20value)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!isArray)%20yield%20prop%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yield*%20traverse(value%5Bprop%5D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0Avar%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20'a'%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20'a1'%3A%20%5B'a1a'%2C%20'a1b'%2C%20'a1c'%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20'a2'%3A%20%5B'a2a'%2C%20'a2b'%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20'a3'%3A%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(Array.from(traverse(obj)))%3B)

---

But it's also not much different without native generators:

```
function traverse(value, result) {
  result = result || [];
  if (typeof value === "object") {
    var isArray = Array.isArray(value);
    for (var prop in value) {
      if (!isArray) result.push(prop);
      traverse(value[prop], result);
    }
  }
  else {
    result.push(value);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(traverse(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard javascript pattern is to pass in a handler function:

```
function traverse(jsonObj, receive) {
    if (typeof jsonObj == "object") {
        if (Array.isArray(jsonObj)) {
            // Don't want to output the keys for arrays
            $.each(jsonObj, function (k, v) {
                traverse(v, receive);
            });

        } else {
            $.each(jsonObj, function (k, v) {
                traverse(k, receive);
                traverse(v, receive);
            });
        }
    } else {
        receive(jsonObj);
    }
}
```

And then here's some example code, which chooses to add each yielded object to an array.

```
var myArray = [];
traverse(myObject, function(jsonObj) { 
                      myArray.push(jsonObj); 
                });
```

Here's a working example, which, instead of pushing to an array, displays each item in the HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/9u3zrjes/1/